# How to import OpenPGP Card / YubiKey backup encryption key

Tags: pgp, smartcard

When I generate a new OpenPGP key on a YubiKey, it gives me the option to save a copy of the encryption key as a backup like so:

```
$ gpg --edit-card

Reader ...........: Yubico Yubikey NEO U2F CCID 00 00
Application ID ...: D2760001240102000006054943550000
Application type .: OpenPGP
Version ..........: 2.0
Manufacturer .....: Yubico
Serial number ....: 05494355
Name of cardholder: [not set]
Language prefs ...: [not set]
Salutation .......: 
URL of public key : [not set]
Login data .......: [not set]
Signature PIN ....: forced
Key attributes ...: rsa2048 rsa2048 rsa2048
Max. PIN lengths .: 127 127 127
PIN retry counter : 3 3 3
Signature counter : 0
Signature key ....: [none]
Encryption key....: [none]
Authentication key: [none]
General key info..: [none]

gpg/card> admin
Admin commands are allowed

gpg/card> generate
Make off-card backup of encryption key? (Y/n) Y
```

Which will result in the keys getting generated on my YubiKey and a file stored in my GNUPGHOME folder like `sk_5F91DF31AB07820C.gpg` which is the encryption key.

My question is how do I import this key back into a usable form if I should ever loose the YubiKey?

- I was expecting a way to create a new key on my local machine and then import this backup key as a new subkey, but I couldn't find a way to do that.
- I see that there is an option under `gpg --edit-key` called `bkuptocard`, which seems to do what I want, but when I try doing that it seems that it only loads the key into the slot on the YubiKey, but doesn't actually make it available for decryption in gpg.

How can I utilize this backup key if I every loose my YubiKey?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make backup of sk_xxx.gpg

Import public key first:

`gpg --import public.pgp`

Add data to not fail with "no user id":

`printf '\xb4\x06foobar' >> sk_xxx.gpg`

Import updated backup key:

`gpg --allow-non-selfsigned-uid --import sk_xxx.gpg`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: works with gpg (GnuPG) 2.3.6

Answer (score 2):

`gpg --import` it.

The file's contents will be stored in your local GnuPG keyring, at which point you can use the subkey directly or move it to a new smartcard if you want.

Comment: That doesn't actually work:
$ gpg --import sk_5F91DF31AB07820C.gpg 
gpg: key 5F91DF31AB07820C: no user ID
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:       secret keys read: 1
$ echo $?
2
$ gpg --list-secret-keys
$

Comment: Sounds like the file only included the subkey and nothing else, so you should import your _public_ key with all metadata (and public subkeys, etc) first; then importing any secret keys will automatically associate them.

Comment: I appreciate the comment, but no, that still doesn't work. gpg returns 2 when it tries to import the backup key (whether or not the public key is present) which means GPG_ERR_UNKNOWN_PACKET. What's strange is `gpg --list-packets sk_5F91DF31AB07820C.gpg` dumps info about the key without error.